# How to track form submit as page view in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a basic AJAX form. On successful submission, I'd like to set the success message as a page view in GA.

I'm trying this:

```
window.ga('send', 'pageview', 'My Form', 'submit')
```

I've heard I need to use Google Tag Manager, but I'd rather simply use the existing GA if I can already in place.

Advice on the best and most simple approach for this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pageview tracking format through the `ga` object is:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);
```

where `page` value should begin with a `/`. Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#implementation).

In your case it would be something like:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/form-submitted', [fieldsObject]);
```

The other option would be to track [virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications). The syntax for tracking virtual pageviews is:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/form-submitted');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```